# Infopath > If select No boolean only then make comments field mandatory

Tags: infopath

Okay, I need to make the comments field in infopath form required only if they select "Reject" a Boolean field. How is it possible?

Comment: I guess I can add rule to the comment field based on user selection. Like, this link http://designshare.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/creating-conditonally-required-fields-in-infopath/

Comment: I tried the link above and Nope it did not help. I keep getting infopath contains validation errors

Comment: Anyone else tried something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the link I provided earlier did work:

[SharePoint for Designers: Creating Conditonally Required Fields in InfoPath](http://designshare.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/creating-conditonally-required-fields-in-infopath/)

Answer (score 0):

- First, make the Comments field mandatory.
- Then, add a new Action to your form: When "Rejected" choosen, set the Comments field value: Comments Value = Comments Value + " ".

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it,

Let's say I have a form like this, where the Approval Status drop down list takes (Pending, Approved, Rejected):

[image: form]

Then, I can apply a data validation like so,

[image: validation]